# TestLink : Change the values of requirements status

Tags: testlink

I need to change the default values ​​of the requirements , the drop-down list , but do not know where to change these values ​​, it is in code or in the database .

I mean the time to describe the terms of reference where we needed to know if the use case, informational or anything else .

Where should I change, delete and insert new values​?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching your question on google led me to the Mantis bug tracker for Testlink where the requirement drop down feature was suggested (in 2010). There it states there is a config or const file that allows you to configure this.

Checking the Testlink installation manual (See: https://github.com/TestLinkOpenSourceTRMS/testlink-code/tree/testlink_1_9/docs) will refer you to a config.inc.php and a custom_config.php.

You will require FTP access to the server hosting your Testlink instance to adjust this file.